# Mysql join heavy query on large tables taking hours

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

I'm trying to query our entire database to build a report and I've run into the problem that I have queries like the one below that are taking near 2 hours to run and some take even longer. I've changed the some of the names but the structure is the same.

Person_table has about 5 million rows

check_table is a subset of Person_table and has about 3 million rows

event_table has about 20 million rows

```
update  check_table as CT
    inner join  
        ( SELECT  B1.id
            from  Person_table as PT
            inner join  event_table as B1  ON PT.id = B1.person_id
            inner join  event_type_table as E using (code_id)
            inner join  
                ( SELECT  *
                    from  event_table as ET
                    where  ET.code_id in ('XYZ','ABC','DEF','ETC.')
                ) as F  ON ET.id = F.person_id
                       and  B1.Event_date = F.event_date
        ) as B2 using (id) set flag_1=1;
```

I've tried to get an explain on many of the queries I have to do but it always spits back a "Explain Data not available for statement".

Comment: Have you applied index to B.person_id and A.code_id and F.person_id fields?

Comment: I think you want to try it such as `EXPLAIN select B.id from Person_table as A
inner join event_table as B on A.id=B.person_id
inner join event_type_table as E using (code_id)
inner join (select * from event_table as A
            where A.code_id in ('XYZ','ABC','DEF','ETC.')) as F
        on A.id = F.person_id
        and B.Event_date = F.event_date) as B using (id)
set flag_1=1;`

Comment: _Please_ do not reuse an alias (`A`); it makes the query hard to read.

Comment: `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` is available only in newer versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may (or may not) be possible to add some composite indexes to speed up the query.  It may (or may not) be possible to reformulate the query to speed it up -- perhaps by turning subqueries into `JOINs`.

But it seems like 3M possible updates will lead to a very slow query in any case.  I suggest chunking the `UPDATE` into no more than 1000 rows at a time.  This will avoid various locks that interfere with other traffic.  And it *may* actually run faster -- due to not needing to hang onto millions of rows for potential `ROLLBACK`.

Discussion of chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

If you want me to check your indexes, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.